# Is there a way of setting up a shortcut to a database for MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms, shortcut

I'd like to have a list of my database servers (I am a developer), I currently have a list of RDP files for different machines I connect to.  Is there a similar feature in SQL Server Management Studio that would help me go directly to where I need to go without me having to wait for the login screen to pop up and ask me which server I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use the following command:

```
ssms.exe -S SERVERNAME -d DATABASENAME -E
```

You can either run this using run, or put it into a .txt file and change the extension to .bat and run that.

Some more information can be found by runing smss.exe /?:

```
Usage:
ssms.exe [-S server_name[\instance_name]] [-d database] [-U user] [-P password] [-E] [file_name[, file_name]] [/?]

    [-S The name of the SQL Server instance to which to connect]
    [-d The name of the SQL Server database to which to connect]
    [-E]    Use Windows Authentication to login to SQL Server
    [-U The name of the SQL Server login with which to connect]
    [-P The password associated with the login]
    [file_name[, file_name]] names of files to load
    [-nosplash] Supress splash screen
    [/?]    Displays this usage information
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you don't need to have this as a .BAT/.CMD file - you can just create a new shortcut to SSMS.exe (copy the one in the Start Menu if you like).  Bring up the properties of the new shortcut and tack your arguments on the end of the 'Target' text box.

Comment: Good point Chris